# Problemas com checkbox(Switchery) toggle

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Boa Tade, estou com um problema em adicionar o *atributo checked* ao checkbox.

Eu tenho conhecimentos em JQuery e já fiz isso muitas outras vezes, mas nunca havia usado Switchery, não sei se é esse o problema, mas deixarei o código **abaixo**.

```
// JQuery
if(data.is_not_found == 1){
    $('#cbxNotFoundMessage').attr("checked", "checked");
}
```

Comment: Já tentou assim:  `$('#cbxNotFoundMessage').attr("checked", true);`

Comment: Sim, não está funcionando dessa forma também

Answer (score 0):

Opa amigo, desse jeito não vai funcionar mesmo por que o atributo checked não tem value !

```
$('#cbxNotFoundMessage').attr('checked','');
```

esse seria o correto.